# My C code doesn't work, it's related to binary trees

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

I want to design a function in C that takes a binary tree as input and determines if the binary tree is symmetric around its center. It doesn't let me input data correctly. In the `main` function, it doesn't take the input requested and when executed the right side input is never asked .

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structure for binary tree node
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

// Function to create a new binary tree node from a given data.
struct Node *newNode(int data) {
    struct Node *node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

// Helper function to check if two subtrees are mirror images of each other.
bool isMirror(struct Node *leftSubtree, struct Node *rightSubtree) {
    if (leftSubtree == NULL && rightSubtree == NULL)
        return true;
    if (leftSubtree == NULL || rightSubtree == NULL)
        return false;
    
    return (leftSubtree->data == rightSubtree->data) &&
           isMirror(leftSubtree->left, rightSubtree->right) &&
           isMirror(leftSubtree->right, rightSubtree->left);
}

// Function to determine if the tree is symmetric.
bool isSymmetric(struct Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return true;
    
    return isMirror(root->left, root->right);
}

// Function to build a binary tree based on user input.
struct Node *buildTree() {
    int data;
    printf("Enter data (-1 for NULL): ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    
    if (data == -1)
        return NULL;
    
    struct Node *newNodePtr = newNode(data);
    printf("Enter left child of %d:\n", data);
    newNodePtr->left = buildTree();
    printf("Enter right child of %d:\n", data);
    newNodePtr->right = buildTree();
    
    return newNodePtr;
}

int main() {
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    printf("Enter the root data:\n");
    root = buildTree();

    if (isSymmetric(root))
        printf("The binary tree is symmetric.\n");
    else
        printf("The binary tree is not symmetric.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: *"when executed the right side input is never asked."*: I cannot reproduce this; it *does* ask for the right side input. What have you input to reproduce this?

Comment: I got the same result as @trincot and the mirror-check seems to work too. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/7Yv6jf6r5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems not to blame for the problem you describe, but there is an issue in `buildTree()`: you do not check the return value of `scanf("%d", &data)`.  If `scanf` successfully converts input as an integer, it will return `1`, otherwise it may return `0` or `EOF` and the value of `data` may still be uninitialized or indeterminate. You should test for success and either report the error or consider `EOF` to mean end of input, hence all remaining nodes should be null.

```
// Function to build a binary tree based on user input.
struct Node *buildTree(void) {
    int data;

    printf("Enter data (-1 for NULL): ");
    switch (scanf("%d", &data)) {
      case EOF:
        return NULL;
      case 0:
        printf("invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
      case 1:
        if (data == -1)
          return NULL;
        break;
    }
    struct Node *newNodePtr = newNode(data);
    printf("Enter left child of %d:\n", data);
    newNodePtr->left = buildTree();
    printf("Enter right child of %d:\n", data);
    newNodePtr->right = buildTree();
    return newNodePtr;
}
```